# How to hide the Editor Group menu in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is this editor group menu box in the top right of the interface in vscode hiding my tabs?  How can I hide or move it?

[image: Editor Group Menu]

Comment: That is the editorGroupHeader and I don't think you can move or hide it yet.  [There are some color customizations for it but that isn't what you are looking for.]

Comment: You can't remove that group menu but you can make your tabs shrink to fit the available space by setting: `"workbench.editor.tabSizing": "shrink"`

Comment: @Alex Myers  sweet! that'll work for now.